# iMacros ondialog conditional statement

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to make `iMacros` send me an email, if after login I get a dialog. In this 
case its a warning that I should update my password before it expires.

I would like some output to **php** that I can use to send the email. I'm presently able to get `getLastExtract` but nothing in the returned array mentions the dialog in any way.

This is the script so far:

```
CODE: SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
TAB T=1     
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS     
URL GOTO=[URL]   
SET !EXTRACTDIALOG YES  
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:adminLogin ATTR=ID:username CONTENT=[username] 
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:adminLogin ATTR=ID:password CONTENT=[password] 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:adminLogin ATTR=VALUE:Login
```

Comment: I think you need to code your macro with JavaScript